# Jenkins with multiple deploys in single Jenkins job

Tags: jenkins

Each application has its own build job and deploy job. I want to create a dashboard of Jenkins job that contains the builds from different applications and can select the application to deploy instead of going to each deploy job page. Can I create multiple deploys in a single Jenkins job? Something that looks like this:

[image: Jenkins with multiple deploys in a single jenkins job]

Comment: I was able to do something similar but the main difference is there is only 1 deploy button in the page. Also in each row above, there is an additional row with checkbox as option to deploy the application or not.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to create some Python and Groovy code for this one.

You can:

1. Divide jobs under different views.
2. Create a job with **Active Parameters** in job configuration
3. Create a groovy script that populates the parameters by fetching jobs view-wise.
4. Write a Python code that uses HTTP calls using REST API of Jenkins, using selected parameters from Step 3, and execute them.

Basically, you can make one executor job which can help you select job names and execute them using Jenkins APIs.

Comment: @alltej you can find the official documentation for Jenkins API [here](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/using/remote-access-api/)

Comment: I know about the documentation but it did not provide solution to my original question above. If you can point me exactly where in the documentation, that will be great.

Comment: @alltej There is no end to end guide for your use-case. You must explore **Jenkins Active Parameters, Groovy Scripts, Jenkins API calls and Python coding basics** for your use case. Also, add **Configuration Slicing Plugin** to the list.

Comment: Question was posted to ask if it can be done or not. I believe it's a `no`.  My workaround is posted in comments.